# Is it fine to ask a collaborator to give me a recommendation letter directly or should I ask my adviser to do so?

Tags: recommendation-letter

Recently, I need to take some recommendation letters from our collaborators but I'm not sure is it fine to ask them directly by myself or should I ask my adviser to do so? Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always better to ask a person directly for the letter of recommendation. That way you can judge the person's enthusiasm and interest in writing a letter. They will also be able to give you more direct information than working through the "middleman" of your advisor.

If you feel uncomfortable approaching your collaborator for a letter, that's probably a sign that you might not get the quality of letter you want.

But you should also mention to your advisor that you are asking your collaborator for a letter, regardless of which path you pursue.

Comment: No, I'm not afraid about the quality just I don't want to look awful as someone that contacted our collaborators without working through the "middleman" as my adviser. Something like: After some while maybe the collaborator says to my adviser that your student got a recommendation letter from me. But my adviser says I didn't know that. And, maybe that looks awful in my adviser eyes that I contact professors without letting him to know. Am I just hesitating too much or it is rational in your opinion?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer So let your advisor know you are going to ask the collaborator for a letter then.

Comment: Why not to ask the advisor what is better to do? He will either propose that he will ask or will tell you to ask.

Comment: @AustinHenley: Thanks for the reminder. I had planned to mention that as part of my answer.

Comment: If you're worried that your request will look like you're going behind your advisor's back, CC your advisor on the request email.